# How to disable a ListView scrolling?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view that always scroll to begining when i adding new itens.
I tried to use: `lv.setSelection(position)`, `lv.ScrollTo(x,y)`, change the onScrollListner of the ListView, but i don't have sucess.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I hope you are using getFirstVisiblePosition() to get position value.

Answer (score 0):

add scrollview to the xml file that your listview will bind with,

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text:"test"
    android:textColor="#000" />
</ScrollView>
```